# Missing data in Thanos at specific resolution

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, thanos

### Question

**Problem**: When querying Thanos for a graph at resolution lower than a certain threshold, Thanos will return data with missing data points when Prometheus does not (see screenshots later).

**Setup**: A kubernetes cluster. Thanos’s querier is configured to query a single Prometheus’s sidecar (I did this as a test, to be certain there would be no downsampling at play here.) The querier is launched *without* the `--query.auto-downsampling` option.

**Question**: Why isn’t Thanos returning all the data Prometheus does?

---

### Graphs

#### Thanos Query for a 12h range, with a 90s resolution

[image: Thanos Query for a 12h range, with a 90s resolution]

#### Same Query, but on Prometheus

[image: Prometheus Query for a 12h range, with a 90s resolution]

#### Thanos Query for a 6h range, with a 90s resolution

[image: Thanos Query for a 6h range, with a 90s resolution]

(We get the same result on Prometheus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by upgrading Thanos from `0.19.0-rc.0` to `0.20.0`…